# How to fix 'Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:' error in c++?

Tags: c++, openmpi

I am writing a program for a class that is supposed to crack passwords that have been salted and encrypted with the unix function 'crypt.' The passwords can be in the form word+number or number+word where the number can be at most three digits long. Example passwords that we should be able to find are like: ant123, 1ant, ant22, 99ant, etc.

I have written a program that does that correctly but now we are supposed to speed it up using Open MPI. It was compiling fine until I tried to implement my Open MPI code but now it is giving me an error.

I am trying to compile with `mpic++ -std=c++11 -Wall main.cc` but the error I get is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "file_IO(int, char**, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >&)", referenced from:
      _main in main-33a67e.o
     (maybe you meant: __Z7file_IOiPPcRNSt3__16vectorINS1_12basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEENS6_IS8_EEEESB_SB_SB_)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

main.cc:

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <mpi.h>

    using namespace std;

    void file_IO(int argc, char *argv[], vector<string> &encPass, vector<string> &words,
                vector<string> &salts);

    void build_guesses(vector<string> &guesses, vector<string> &words);
    void crack(string pass, vector<string> &salts, vector<string> &guesses);

    void broadcast_receive(vector<string> &encPass, vector<string> &words, vector<string> &salts,
                           vector<string> &guesses, int numProcesses, int procNum);

    vector<char> convert(vector<string> &strings);

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        vector<string> encPass;
        vector<string> words;
        vector<string> salts;
        vector<string> guesses;

        int numProcesses;
        int procNum;

        MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProcesses);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procNum);

        if(procNum == 0) {
            file_IO(argc, argv, encPass, words, salts);
            build_guesses(guesses, words);
        }

        else {
            broadcast_receive(encPass, words, salts, guesses, numProcesses, procNum);

            for(size_t i = 0; i < encPass.size(); i++) {
                size_t del = encPass[i].rfind("$");
                string pass = encPass[i].substr(del);
                crack(pass, salts, guesses);
            }
        }

        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
    }


    void file_IO(int argc, char *argv[], vector<string> &encPass, vector<string> &words,
                vector<string> &salts, vector<string> &passwords) {

        if(argc < 3) {
            cout << "One or more files were not specified." << endl;
            cout << "Correct format is './a.out file1 file2'" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        ifstream secretPass(argv[1]);
        string singlePass;

        while(getline(secretPass, singlePass)) {
            encPass.push_back(singlePass);
        }

        secretPass.close();

        ifstream dictionary(argv[2]);
        string word;

        while(getline(dictionary, word)) {
            words.push_back(word);
        }

        dictionary.close();

        ifstream salt("salts");
        string s;

        while(getline(salt, s)) {
            salts.push_back(s);
        }

        salt.close();
    }

    void build_guesses(vector<string> &guesses, vector<string> &words) {
        //one word and one number
        for(size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            for(size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                guesses.push_back(words[i] + to_string(j));
            }
        }

        //one number and one word
        for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for(size_t j = 0; j < words.size(); j++) {
                guesses.push_back(to_string(i) + words[j]);
            }
        }

        //one word and two numbers
        for(size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            for(size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                for(size_t x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                    guesses.push_back(words[i] + to_string(j) + to_string(x));
                }
            }
        }

        //two numbers and one word
        for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for(size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                for(size_t x = 0; x < words.size(); x++) {
                    guesses.push_back(to_string(i) + to_string(j) + words[x]);
                }
            }
        }

        //one word and three numbers
        for(size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            for(size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                for(size_t x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                    for(size_t y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
                        guesses.push_back(words[i] + to_string(j) + to_string(x) + to_string(y));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //three numbers and one word
        for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for(size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                for(size_t x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                    for(size_t y = 0; y < words.size(); y++) {
                        guesses.push_back(to_string(i) + to_string(j) + to_string(x) + words[y]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void crack(string pass, vector<string> &salts, vector<string> &guesses) {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < salts.size(); i++) {
            for(size_t j = 0; j < guesses.size(); j++) {
                string ep = crypt(guesses[j].c_str(), salts[i].c_str());

                if(ep.compare(salts[i] + pass) == 0) {
                    cout << "Password: " + guesses[j] << endl;
                }
            }
        }

        cout << "Password not found" << endl;
    }

    void broadcast_receive(vector<string> &encPass, vector<string> &words, vector<string> &salts,
                           vector<string> &guesses, int numProcesses, int procNum) {

        int buffer[4];

        buffer[0] = encPass.size();
        buffer[1] = words.size();
        buffer[2] = salts.size();

        MPI_Bcast(buffer, 3, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        encPass.resize(buffer[0]);
        words.resize(buffer[1]);
        salts.resize(buffer[2]);

        vector<char> ep = convert(encPass);
        vector<char> w = convert(words);
        vector<char> s = convert(salts);
        vector<char> g = convert(guesses);

        MPI_Bcast(ep.data(), ep.size(), MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(w.data(), w.size(), MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(s.data(), s.size(), MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(g.data(), g.size(), MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    vector<char> convert(vector<string> &strings) {
        vector<char> cstrings;
        cstrings.reserve(strings.size());

        for(string s : strings) {
            for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(s.c_str()); i++) {
                cstrings.push_back(s.c_str()[i]);
            }
        }

        return cstrings;
    }
```

When I comment out `file_IO(argc, argv, encPass, words, salts);` the program compiles without warnings or errors but I'm not sure why this function is causing an issue since it compiled fine before I added the Open MPI code.

Comment: Your function body has one more argument than both its forward declaration and its user (call site).  That parameter is never used, but it still is part of the function signature.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thank you! I looked over it so many times. I can't believe I missed that!